# Check if a git repo exists in a shell script

Tags: git, bash

Is there a way to check if a git repo exists using a bash or csh script? I know that we can use `git ls-remote <repository>` to check the existence of the remote repo. But I'd like to somehow do this programatically in a shell script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write the command in the script itself:

```
~$ git ls-remote <existing_repo> -q
~$ echo $?
0
```

0 means that the repo was found, otherwise you'll get a non-zero value.

[`-q`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html) is for:

> quiet (Do not print remote URL to stderr.)

Comment: Is there a way to suppress the output when the repo does not exist?

Comment: is 2>&1 required or can I just use >& ?

Comment: @BigBrownBear00 If I'm not mistaken, they are both the same. But I'm not sure yours will work on all shells. I usually use: `>/dev/null 2>&1` to suppress all output.

Comment: `>&` is a extension found in `bash` and some other shells. `2>&1` will work in any POSIX-compliant shell.