# Safely check if public GitHub repo exists in bash without login?

Tags: bash, git, github, silent

### Context

While trying out [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45958778/7437143) provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45958733/check-if-a-git-repo-exists-in-a-shell-script) on how to check if a GitHub repository exists using bash, I notice that the command asks for credentials and throws an error if the repository is not found:

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/some_git_user/some_non_existing_repo_name -q
Username for 'https://github.com': some_git_user 
Password for 'https://some_git_user@github.com': 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/some_git_user/some_non_existing_repo_name/' not found
(base) somename@somepcname:~$ echo $?
128
```

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1678051/809273) seems to prevent `git` from asking credentials.

### Issues

0. Being asked for credentials is fine in other scenarios, so I would prefer to not disable `git` from asking credentials system-wide. Yet still, I would like the function to run automatically without asking for credentials, as they are not needed for a check to a public repository.
1. The command yields an error status 128 if it does not find the repository. Instead, I would like to safely check if the repository is found or not, without raising an error. E.g. by producing outputs `echo "FOUND"` or `echo "NOTFOUND"`.

### Question

How can one test if a public GitHub repository exists in bash, without being prompted for credentials, without raising an error?

### Details

The user has not provided any ssh-key nor credentials to/in the script.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you interested (1) in public GitHub repositories, (2) in private ones, or (3) in both? For (2)-(3), has the user of the script a public SSH key registered in GitHub?

Comment: Confirmed (1) public GitHub repositories only. Not interested in (2) private ones. Not interested in (3) both public and private repositories. The user has not provided any ssh-key nor credentials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to easily check if a public repository exists on GitHub, you actually need not `git` nor any credentials: you can make a simple HTTP request to the [GitHub REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository).

Proof-of-concept:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exists_public_github_repo() {
  local user_slash_repo=$1

  if curl -fsS "https://api.github.com/repos/${user_slash_repo}" >/dev/null; then
    printf '%s\n' "The GitHub repo ${user_slash_repo} exists." >&2
    return 0
  else
    printf '%s\n' "Error: no GitHub repo ${user_slash_repo} found." >&2
    return 1
  fi
}


if exists_public_github_repo "ocaml/ocaml"; then
  echo "OK"
fi
```

For more details on the `curl` command itself and the flags `-f`, `-s`, `-S` I used, you can browse its [man page](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html) online.