# Check if public GitHub repository exists without using api, using bash?

Tags: bash, github

### Context

After having applied [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71068773/7437143), I noticed I got rate limiting after calling the function 5 times in a span of +-3 minutes. I expect this may have been because someone in the location/ip in which I was testing the function, was already consuming some of the API bandwith. So I added a personal access token to the API call to overcome the API rate limiting.

However, this check is used in an installation script in that does not have access to a GitHub personal access token. Hence, I would like to use a more robust check on whether a GitHub repository exists. I think this is possible, because regardless of the API rate-limiting, I am able to go to the website (https://www.github.com/some_github_user/some_github_repository) and see whether the repository exists.

### Question

Hence, I would like to ask, how can one check if a public GitHub repository exists, without using the GitHub API, in bash?

Comment: wget or curl to check the response of the website perhaps?

Comment: Are you looking at only public repos?  As if you have a private repo and try to access it without auth, you'll get a 404, same as if that repo doesn't exist.

Comment: @JohnLBevan thank you, I added I only look at a public repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to fetch the main repository page using `curl` with the `--fail` option (which causes `curl` to return an error code in response to HTTP errors):

```
if curl --silent --fail https://github.com/someperson/somerepo; then
  echo repository exists
else
  echo repository does not exist
fi
```

As pointed out in comments, this will *only* work for public repositories; access a private repository without authentication behaves the same as an attempt to access a repository that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the clear feedback, I had some difficulties in getting the quotations correct with variables, and silencing the output, so I wrote a function based on the `curl` and `--silent` aspects of larsks answer.

```bash
check_public_github_repository_exists_without_api() {
    local github_username
    github_username="$1"
    local github_repo
    github_repo="$2"

    local url
    url="https://github.com/$github_username/$github_repo"
    
    # Get website head(er) content
    local website_head_content
    website_head_content="$(curl -s --head $url)"
    
    # Get the first line of the website head(er) content.
    local first_line=`echo "${website_head_content}" | head -1`
    
    # Remove trailing characters with xargs
    local website_status=$(echo "$first_line" | xargs)
    
    if [[ "$website_status" == "HTTP/2 200" ]]; then
        echo "FOUND"
    elif [[ "$website_status" == "HTTP/2 404" ]]; then
        echo "NOTFOUND"
    else
        echo "Error, unexpected website status response: $website_status for: $url"
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

Comment: `if curl -ILsf "https://github.com/$github_username/$github_repo" >/dev/null; then echo "It's up"; else echo 'Oh no!'; fi`